# Fail instead of allocate from swap

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, swap, virtual-memory

Is there a way to detect if a memory allocation would cause the program to swap? Or if the last memory allocation causes swap to be used?

Basically, I'm debugging memory leaks in a VM and I want the program to terminate instead of using swap memory because that locks up the whole computer so I have to hard reboot.

I do not want to disable swap memory on the machine globally because that can have unintended consequences for legitimate users of swap memory.

Example code and names of API calls to perform this task on Windows and Linux would be appreciated.

I know Linux has a system call for keeping a process in memory, it's not the same thing as I'm asking for. `setrlimit` isn't quite right either because the amount of physical RAM free could change a lot during execution.